# Offline cache size limit for Firefox Mobile

Tags: html, firefox, caching, mobile, html5-appcache

I am developing a web app that uses an appcache manifest for offline use. One of the files to be cached is relatively large (13.6 MB). The caching works as expected in Firefox desktop, both as a web app and as a normal web page. However, the offline caching of the large file doesn't seem to be working in Firefox mobile, either as a web app or in the regular browser mode. Is there a offline cache size limit in Firefox mobile? I have found [this site](http://grinninggecko.com/developing-cross-platform-html5-offline-app-1/) about limits, but didn't see anything about Firefox mobile. I have also looked extensively at the Mozilla documentation. Thanks for any help.